# ¿como puedo hacer una timeline paginada en laravel? Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sql-server, laravel-livewire

estoy haciendo un proyecto en **laravel 10** el cual muestra las incidencias de una empresa y necesito mostrarlas en una linea de tiempo por fecha y como pueden ser muchos reportes solo quiero que salgan 10 por pagina, para esto agrupo la coleccion por fecha y despues lo pagineo pero esto no funciona ya que solo paginea las 'fechas' `'2022-03-12 => [ reportes...]'` y yo necesito paginar los reportes y salgan 10 por pagina.

Este es mi codigo:

```
class ClientBuzonIndexComponent extends BaseClientDateSelectListenerComponent
{
protected $reports;
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
protected $select = ["fCaptura","tipo_reportes_id","descripcion","idEmpleado","idReporte"];
public $employees;

public function mount()
{
    $this->employees = auth()->user()->cliente->empleados();
    parent::mount();
}

protected function onUpdate($year, $month)
{
    $reports = TbReporte::select($this->select)->whereYear('fCaptura',$year)->whereMonth('fCaptura',$month)->whereIn('idEmpleado',$this->employees->pluck('idEmpleado'))->get();
    $this->reports = $reports->groupBy('fCaptura')->paginate(10);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.client.buzon.client-buzon-index-component',[
        'paginateAnswers' => $this->reports
    ]);
}
}
```

esta es la macro que cree para la paginacion de colecciones

```
Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage,$total = null,$page = null,$pageName = null){
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page,$perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page ,
            [
                'path' =>LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
                'pageName' => $pageName
            ]
        );
    });
```

En resumen no se como paginar una timeline en la cual quiero que salgan 10 reportes y esten agrupadas por la fecha del reporte